# Import json data into redis

Tags: ruby, redis, sinatra

i'm new to redis and ruby i'm using the following code

```
response = HTTParty.get('posts.json')
json = JSON(response.body)

json.each do |item|
    puts item
    puts json[item]
    puts item['content']
    redis.hset 'latest_posts', item, item['title']
end

puts json[item]
```

returns the following `error no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer`

inside each loop i want to output the keys for example id, title, content with puts item (now returns the whole object) and with json[item] data in keys any help? if i try for example

```
%w{id title content}.each do |key|
        puts key
        puts json[key]
end
```

again `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

Comment: What is `json` assigned to? Are you sure you're using that correctly? Normally you see `JSON.load(response.body)`.

Comment: i'm using HTTParty for loading json is a variable assigned to json object just a name

Comment: You should `puts json.inspect` on the third line to be sure it's the right type. The error you're getting is often what happens when you call `[]` on a string or an array. Also `puts json[item].inspect` as well in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems that you expect an array of hashes in your JSON.

I see two problems here:

1.

```
puts json[item]
puts item['content']
```

an `item` is a hash. `json[item]` makes no sense to me.

2.

```
redis.hset 'latest_posts', item, item['title']
```

is supposed to set a key `item` in the Redis hash `'latest_posts'` to the value `item['title']`. But `item` is a hash, and, I think, Redis expects a string as the filed name.

BTW, is not it `JSON.parse response.body`?